# I want to take out only the numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Development enviroment
・ react
・ typescript
・ yarn

I want to cut out only numbers using match
But I get an error

error message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`

```
const name="19 years old"
name.match(/[0-9]*/g)
```

Answer (score 1):

The name property is defined on the window object.

Use another variable name and it'll be alright:

```
const nameVar="19 years old"
nameVar.match(/[0-9]*/g)
```

Another thing you can do is make your TS file a module so that it has its own namespace. in order to make a TS file a module, you should import or export from the file. so the below code would again work:

```
const name="19 years old"
name.match(/[0-9]*/g)

export {}
```

Comment: _"The name property is defined on the window object."_ - kinda misleading. The error clearly says that its _undefined_.

Comment: I fixed it in namaVar and got an error

Comment: This answer is potentially harmful. `name` **is not** a reserved keyword in javascript. You can declare variables with `name` as it's name. Anyways, even if `name` is a window object, by declaring it in your function it gets scoped or/and overwritten. Feel free to remove it.

Comment: An error is displayed. Where should I fix it?

Comment: @TOYUU, @kinduser is right. I can't see how `TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined` can occur. the error that happens with the OP code is `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name'.` please share a TS playground link to investigate it further.